# Segementation fault when playing midi notes with pygame.midi

Tags: python, audio, pygame, segmentation-fault, midi

I've been trying to write a simple python program in PyCharm that can play midi notes using pygame.midi. It seems like I can initialize and quit pygame.midi just fine, like so:

```
import pygame
import pygame.midi
import time

pygame.midi.init()

pygame.midi.quit()
```

The code above returns no errors, however, as soon as I try to play notes with pygame.midi, i get an error message. Here is the code that gives me the error message:

```
import pygame
import pygame.midi
import time

pygame.midi.init()

player = pygame.midi.Output(0)
player.set_instrument(42)
player.note_on(60, 127)
time.sleep(3)
player.note_off(60, 127)

pygame.midi.quit()
```

And here is the error message:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x000040fc (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Geh\xf8rprogram_V3\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\midi.py", line 422 in __init__
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Geh\xf8rprogram_V3/krasjtest.py", line 7 in <module>
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest version of pygame:

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

To avoid issues run cmd or powershell as administrator. Or make sure you specified this version in PyCharm. But I advise you to try to run it in IDLE first. This should solve the issue.